# DataGrid - rows per page dropdown is absent

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

According to DataGrid Material-UI API, the rowsPerPage dropdown has to be present in the TableFooter, as in the official documentation here:

https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/pagination/#page-size
[image]
But when I open this example in CodeSandbox, this feature is absent at the UI:
https://codesandbox.io/s/f8fv5
[image]
How can I add rowsPerPage in my DataGrid?

Answer (score 1):

The rowsPerPage dropdown seems to be hidden when the media width is not enough. Try to widen the preview pane of [your CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/f8fv5).

These styles are applied to the dropdown by MUI.

```css
.makeStyles-caption-2[id] {
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width:960px) {
  .makeStyles-caption-2[id] {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `rowsPerPageOptions` as given below

```
 <DataGrid
  pageSize={pageSize}
  onPageSizeChange={(newPageSize) => setPageSize(newPageSize)}
  rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 20]}
  pagination
  {...data}
/>
```

Comment: The example has this prop passed to DataGrid component, but the dropdown is still absent at the page. Please read the answer here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/issues/1992

Comment: This is the correct answer for me 

/* add a state */
const [PageSize,setPageSize]=useState(5)

     <DataGrid
      pagination
      pageSize={PageSize}
      onPageSizeChange={(newPageSize) => setPageSize(newPageSize)}
      rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 20]}
      {...data}
    />